# VS 2010 seems to not be associating with razor(no highlighting or intellisense)

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I installed mvc 3.0 but it seems like my visual studios 2010 ultimate edition is not associating to it. I get to syntex highlighting, intellisense not even the file icons for .cshtml.

http://img228.imageshack.us/img228/306/screenshot004ob.jpg

I reinstalled mvc 3.0, 3 times and I removed resharper so that does not seem to be the problem. I created both empty and the demo application and get the same results for both.

I am not sure why I am not getting it. I can seem to build and run the application no problem.

when I click on .cshtml file and click open with(through VS 2010) I see that it opens it with a xml editor. Is this what it should be opening it up with?

http://img35.imageshack.us/i/screenshot005oy.jpg/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Older versions of ReSharper interfere with Razor InteliSense. Looks like you need at least 5.1.2: http://blogs.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2011/01/resharper-512-is-released/

Comment: How old is old? I had 5.1 installed then I saw something saying that older versions interfere with Razor so I went and downloaded 5.2(the down load file though was labeled like 5.1.7 or something like that. Yet I still had the same problem. So I uninstalled mvc3 for now and going to reinstall with resharper disabled and hope it works.

Comment: 5.2? 5.1.7? The latest version of ReSharper is 5.1.2.

Comment: when I go to http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/ and  click on download resharper 5.1.2 I get an msi file for -> 5.1.1766.4.msi

Comment: You would have to ask JetBrains about the inconsistency in their version numbers.

Comment: Ok I don't think it is resharper. I unistalled it and it still is not right. I even unistalled mvc 3.0 and reinstalled. See my edit.